# There is no output at Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
var letters: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for c in letters {
    print(c, terminator: "")
}
```

I am a totally new in swift programming. I use Xcode 9 Beta version.
When I compile the code there is no output but if I wrote any thing outside the for a loop the immediately it will show in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you write a print statement without a newline as the terminator, it will only write into a buffer. The buffer is flushed when you print a newline.

To print a newline, just use an empty `print()` statement:

```
var letters: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for c in letters {
    print(c, terminator: "")
}
// Print a newline here, so everything gets flushed.
print()
```

Comment: Is there some mechanism to check or print the buffer

Comment: You can print the buffer by calling the `print()` function. If you want to flush your output without appending a newline, you can call `fflush(stdout)`, which flushes the contents of the internal buffer (but I would strongly discourage to do so and it likely doesn't work in Playgrounds). The Swift `print()` function uses an output stream, which is `_StdOut` by default. `_StdOut` uses `fwrite(...)` and `putchar(...)`, which are buffered. By flushing the buffer, its contents are printed. I don't know of any way to read the buffer contents and you should never rely on the contents of that buffer.